# Multiple Linear Regression - P values = 0

Tags: linear-regression, forecasting, p-value

So I am new to multiple linear regression and something in my analysis has gone horribly wrong. To explain some background, I am looking at the hiring of electric cars over a 6 month period with the following data points:

- Count no. of trips from each station on each day (1,2,3 etc)
- Charging stations (ID of the station),
- one time hire or subscription customer (0,1)
- Total no. charging stations ports available (1,2,3, etc)
- Cars available (1,2,3,4)
- no. of charging stations ports available (1,2,3, etc on the date)
- Mean Temp (10,11,12, etc.)

I've used the following code to output OLS regression results.

```
Y = train_set['Count no. of trips per station on each day']
X =train_set[['start_station_id','subscription_type','cars_available','docks_available','mean_temperature_C']]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
lin_reg = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()  
lin_reg.summary()
```

What I want to do is predict the total no. of trips taken each day from each station using these variables and then use this to forecast the output for the same 6 months the following year.

When I enter the above, the majority of the P values for the variables come back as 0. I appreciate it is difficult without the data however its proprietary so I can't share. Is it because I have excluded the date data from the analysis?